# Setting multiple certificates on an aws_lb_listener using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate, terraform

Using terraform, is there a way using aws_lb_listener to set multiple certificate arn?

Practicallyit seems "certificate_arn" field is accepting only one certificate arn. Is there a trick to add multiple certificates arn?

Something like:

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "https" {
  certificate_arn     = ["${var.certificate1_arn}", "${var.certificate2_arn}"]

}
```

Answer (score 14):

Seems like this is possible now with https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lb_listener_certificate.html

> This resource is for additional certificates and does not replace the default certificate on the listener.

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "front_end" {
  # ...
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_certificate" "example" {
  listener_arn    = "${aws_lb_listener.front_end.arn}"
  certificate_arn = "${aws_acm_certificate.example.arn}"
}
```

Comment: This approach is still really annoying for HTTPS listeners, which require a certificate be applied on the listener resource itself.  This means that if you want multiple certificates you have to cleverly apply one to the main resource and then others using this attachment strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Hashicorp terraform currently not supporting attaching multiple SSL certificates.

Although AWS ALB supports multiple SSL certificates.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/10/elastic-load-balancing-application-load-balancers-now-support-multiple-ssl-certificates-and-smart-certificate-selection-using-server-name-indication-sni/

You can use aws cloudformation though.

Comment: Piggy backing on this, since this is the right answer. However, OP can use a cloud formation template that is managed by terraform as a "work around".

Comment: There's an open pull request for it: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/2203